# disable a link after it's selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

when i click on link it gets a class named selected after it gets this class it needs to be disabled until it loses the class "selected" but it can't affect other `li` without class or with class "none"

```
    function abrePlanta(idPlanta, desc, image){
    h = screen.height;

    if ($('li').hasClass("selected")) {
        return false;
    }

    $('#image_preview').html('<img src="../interface_test/images/loading.gif" />');
    $('ul li.selected').removeClass('selected').addClass('none');
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('selected').removeAttr("disabled");

    if(h >= 960){
       size = 100;
    } else if(h < 960){
        size = 90;
    }

   $.get('2.php', { id_planta: idPlanta, size: size }, function(img){
        $('#image_preview').html(img);
   });
   $('#description').html(desc);
   $("#imagezoom").attr("src", "../../images/plantas/sso/" + image);
   return false;
}

<li><a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick="return abrePlanta.call(this, 2, "text", "image.jpg")"></a></li>
```

and it doesn't work `event.preventDefault`

i'm using `onclick` with a function

Comment: But when you click on a link, won't the browser follow that link to whatever location it points to ?

Comment: no.. it's ajax and it can't activate ajax twice in same link @adeneo

Comment: But then you already have another event handler for that element for the ajax call, and creating a new handler that returns false won't work ?

Comment: Are you sure you're not just looking for `one()` ?

Comment: my function calls ajax and pass arguments btu i need to check it inside this function after a li selected it can't be selected again only others @adeneo

Comment: Why are you using in-line event-handling when you have jQuery?

Comment: it's the only way that i know i guess like this `onclick="myfunction("some text", 1, "some word")"` @DavidThomas

Comment: @EddieD. make sure to 'return' the results of the function: `return myfunction(...)`

Comment: i did it.. but nothing @Richard

Comment: @EddieD. you added the js but removed the html.  Could you add that too.

Comment: oh sorry.. done @Rooster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hard to tell without seeing more of your code, but at a glance

Change:

```
if($(this).hasclass('selected')){
```

to

```
if($(this).hasClass('selected')){
```

capital C in hasClass

Also, based on your edit, right now you're checking all `li` elements in the document for the selected class with:

```
if ($('li').hasClass("selected")) {
    return false;
}
```

You should just be checking the li thats wrapping the a thats clicked if I understand what you're asking. So do something like this instead(this assumes that idPlanta is a js reference to the link that is clicked which is what it looks like you're trying, but can't be certain because your code didn't compile in a js fiddle when I tried to build it),

```
if ($(idPLanta).parent().hasClass("selected")) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: like I said hard to tell without seeing more of your code.  What I pointed out is definitely a problem though.  If you want a more concise answer post a js fiddle or your complete code.

Comment: @EddieD. see my edited answer, even if that doesn't solve your problem entirely, it should at least let you move on to the next part of it.

Comment: it worked like this `if ($(this).parent().hasClass.("selected")) { return false; else { ajax here }`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WYcFn/1/) that may help you figure some things out...

---

Your problem is where you declare the function:

```
<a href="#" onclick="myfunction()">test2</a>
```

This will call the function (which returns true/false), but it doesn't do anything with it.  To cancel the event bubbling, you need to return the results of the function:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return myfunction()">test2</a>
```

This will return the "false" from the function, which will cancel the natural click event.

Comment: even using another name it still not working.. when i use this if my function stop working

Comment: that's exactly what i need.. i mean ur example but when i use this if my ajax doesn't work i put it in the beginning of the function

Answer (score 0):

```
if($(this).hasClass('selected')){
    $(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
    return false;
} 
else {
    return true;
}

$('ul li.selected').removeClass('selected').addClass('none');
$(this).closest('li').addClass('selected').removeAttr("disabled");

<li><a href="#" onclick="function()">test</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="function()">test2</a></li>
```